# "Holy Spirit" or "Holy Ghost"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology, differences

Until today I believed that both terms are basically the same.

But our English teacher told us that the correct term is *Holy Spirit*.

Is there any difference between *Holy Spirit* and *Holy Ghost*? I know a song whom lyrics say: *I've got the Holy Ghost down in my soul*.

When should we use *Holy Spirit* and *Holy Ghost*?

BTW, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Spirit) says:

> Holy Spirit, **or Holy Ghost**, is a term found in English translations of the Bible, but understood differently among the Abrahamic religions

Comment: try asking on http://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you asked your teacher for their authority in choosing one as the 'correct' term? I can find a lot of authorities saying that neither is incorrect (though _Holy Ghost_ is a rather more old-fashioned sounding name).

Comment: No, there is no difference between them, and they are for all intents and purposed interchangeable. In my limited experience, *Holy Ghost* is more often used by Catholics and Mormons, while *Holy Spirit* by protestants.

Comment: @Ian I am asking here for the *English meaning*. Thank you, I will ask there for the religious meanings.

Comment: 'Holy Ghost' and 'Holy Spirit' are proper nouns, and as such aren't covered in any great depths by 'normal rules of English'. Whether the tie-in with the various meanings of the English words 'ghost' and 'spirit' would favour one choice above the other is largely irrelevant. Both have senses 'a being not (usually) manifesting in typical fleshly / space-time-matter form '.

Comment: If your teacher opposes _ghost_ for its connotations, _spirit_ has even more non-religious connotations (as in alcohol). These arguments should not be relevant, but if your teacher insists... :)

Comment: The word _spirit_ is the Latin word for the English word _ghost_. Both mean 'soul, non-corporeal being'. When England became Christian, Latin terms began to make their way into the language. One of the phrases "Holy Spirit" and "Holy Ghost" is generally preferred traditionally by one or another Christian denomination. When I was growing up Catholic in the 1950s, we were taught _Holy Ghost_ as the norm, but we also recognized _Holy Spirit_ in some prayers. Your mileage may vary if you acculturated in a different time, place, or sect.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about potentially subtle theological distinctions which should more properly be addressed on [christianity.SO](christianity.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The holy ghost became known as the holy spirit after a lot of boos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the term 'Holy Ghost' was coined, the word 'ghost' meant the spiritual essence of a person, and the Holy Ghost was (loosely) the spiritual essence of God. Nowadays 'ghost' usually means a creepy things that hangs around after death and haunts people, which isn't what was originally intended.

Because of this, in modern usage the term 'Holy Spirit' is generally preferred. However 'Holy Ghost' is also well understood and fairly frequently used (especially in older Bible translations) and means the same thing.